# UIimage not appearing over scrollview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

Need to scroll the scrollview horizontally and with images under it.
It is scrolling horizontally but cannot see my images over it even after the changing the background. Please find the code below :-

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic , weak) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.window.frame.size.width/5)*i, 0, self.view.window.frame.size.width/5, 48)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"t3"];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [_scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}

_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.window.frame.size.width, 48.0f);
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
      }

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a break point in your loop and check the frames of your imageviews and check that you image "t3" is actually being loaded.

Other things you could change,

1. You don't need to use self.view.window.frame, just use self.view.frame.
2. You add your scrollview to your view, but it's an IBOutlet, you don't need to do this if you already have it in the hierarchy on the storyboard or xib.

If you still have problems please comment, good luck.

Comment: Thanks alot..You don't need to use self.view.window.frame, just use self.view.frame.(this is the problem)

Comment: Cool, if possible could you help accept my answer, let me know if there are any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about `self.view.window`.

From Apple's document, is says that

> This property is `nil` if the view has not yet been added to a window.

You have not added `self.view` to a window yet, so if you use

```
NSLog(@"self.view.window: %@", self.view.window);
```

the log will be

> self.view.window: (null)

That is to say, the value of `self.view.window.frame.size.width` is 0.

So the solution is easy:

Use `self.view.frame.size.width` instead of `self.view.window.frame.size.width`.

**OR** use the code below to add `self.view` to a window

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] addSubview:self.view];
```

Comment: thanx mate.. nice explanation